# How do I get keepWhen behaviour in Elm 0.15?

Tags: functional-programming, frp, elm

The `keepWhen` function from earlier versions of Elm was removed. I have ported an Elm application from 0.14, but I'm stuck at trying to get one part of it to work, where it's using `keepWhen`.

So basically I'm looking for a function like

```
keepWhen : Signal Bool -> a -> Signal a -> Signal a
```

I have found

```
filter : (a -> Bool) -> a -> Signal a -> Signal a
```

but it's not quite the same thing, and I haven't figured out how to get it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Answer: import it from a utility package

The easiest way is to use [`Signal.Extra.keepWhen`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/Apanatshka/elm-signal-extra/4.0.1/Signal-Extra#keepWhen) from the [signal-extra](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/Apanatshka/elm-signal-extra/4.0.1/) package.
(full disclosure: I'm the author)

## Important implementation detail

Notice that the implementation isn't completely trivial. This is the implementation in the package (the `Signal` module is imported unqualified):

```
keepWhen : Signal Bool -> a -> Signal a -> Signal a
keepWhen boolSig a aSig =
  zip boolSig aSig
  |> sampleOn aSig
  |> keepIf fst (True, a)
  |> map snd
```

The important difference with the version in [kqr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29870884/859279) is the `sampleOn` which keeps the output of `keepWhen` from updating when the boolean input changes. The difference between the two filters is that the `keepWhen` from 0.14 really only filters update events from the `a` input and doesn't sample it when the boolean input becomes `True`.

The other implementation is also in signal-extra under the name [`sampleWhen`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/Apanatshka/elm-signal-extra/4.0.1/Signal-Extra#sampleWhen).

### Diagrams

If you know a little about marble diagrams, maybe [these](http://share-elm.com/sprout/553c73a9e4b06aacf0e8986a/0.12.3/view) [old diagrams](http://share-elm.com/sprout/553c72cfe4b06aacf0e89868/0.12.3/view) may help. I'll just post a screenshot of the relevant ones below.

The way you read these diagrams:

1. Time flows from left to right.
2. A line is a signal.
3. The block is a function that takes the two signals above and produces the signal below.
4. The shape at the left of each line is the initial value.
5. A filled shape is an event on a signal.
6. An outlined shape is for when the signal doesn't change.
7. I've used shapes to represent types.
8. I've used colours to represent different values.

[image: keepWhen and older keepWhen+sample marble diagrams]

Note that the second diagram, labeled as old behaviour, matches the behaviour of the code in kqr's answer.

Comment: Very elegant! I heard there was a difference between pre-0.12 keepWhen and the "modern" version, but I didn't manage to understand the difference until your very clear exposition now. Thanks a tonne!

Answer (score 2):

I have reimplemented `keepWhen` in terms of `Signal.filter` in Elm 0.15. This rests on the observation that `Signal.filter` uses the value of the signal to decide whether to drop or keep the signal value, and the fact that you can combine two signals to get a new signal (`Signal.map2 (,)`).

If you combine the `Signal Bool` you have with the `Signal a` you eventually want, you'll get a `Signal (a, Bool)` where you can, in the `Signal.filter`, just extract the `Bool` value to decide whether or not you want to keep that value.

The function looks like this:

```
keepWhen : Signal Bool -> a -> Signal a -> Signal a
keepWhen cond def val =
  let combined = Signal.map2 (,) val cond
      filtered = Signal.filter snd (def, False) combined
      final    = Signal.map fst filtered
  in  final
```

It first pairs up the "value" signal with the `Bool` signal to get a `Signal (a, Bool)`. Then it filters that signal based on the `Bool` in it, and finally it strips off the `Bool` and keeps only the "real" value.

You can see it working here: http://share-elm.com/sprout/553c01afe4b06aacf0e8985a . If you have the mouse close to the (0,0) corner it will not update, but when you move the mouse farther to the bottom right it will start updating the signal again.